# Counting minutes/seconds

Tags: google-sheets

I am using format-value-time to have cells where I input minutes/seconds, like 13:45 for 13 minutes & 45 seconds. If I have several of these cells, how can I add them all up?

**Example:**

Cell1:
00.13.45

Cell2:
00.05.12

Cell3:
Should display cell1 + cell2 in the format 00.18.57

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that quite easy with a summation (do use **colons (:)** in the notation):

- `A1=00:13:45`
- `A2=00:05:12`

Then use `SUM` formula:

- `SUM(A1:A2)`

The result will be: `00:18:57`

**UPDATE 18-01-2013**
See example file I´ve created: [Google Spreadsheets: Counting minutes/seconds](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdGdPTm5hbzFmb2dxUmh4ekVVTGNhamc)

If you use Neo's formula, to get rid of the points, in combination with an `ARRAYFORMULA` you will get the result as well:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(TIME(LEFT(B2:B3,2), MID(B2:B3,4,2), RIGHT(B2:B3,2))))`

See example file (+1 for Neo)

Comment: It could have problem if the summation of hour is more than 24. The cells hide date value.

Comment: @neo: it doesn't affect hours beyond 24 hours, see example file. -1 for you.

Comment: haha. I set the column format to time but it couldn't beyond 24 hours. +1 for you.

Comment: "do use double point in the notation" I've always heard this called a colon. Is "double point" correct for time notation?

Comment: @spex I guess you're right !! I have an excuse though: I'm Dutch....Why don't you edit my answer and make the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Below should help,

```
=TIME(LEFT(A1,2), MID(A1,4,2), RIGHT(A1,2))+TIME(LEFT(A2,2), MID(A2,4,2), RIGHT(A2,2))
```